# Spring Webclient versus Feign client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, webclient, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Hi I am looking detail comparision between spring webclient and feignclient. As I understand webclient replace resttemplate and extra features reactive client, retry, exception handling vs. Is there Any known sceneraio feign client do but webclient doesnt. I prefer to stay spring ecosystem rather than use external library.For that reason I think to give up using feign client , and start to use webclient. Is there Any issue about or experience about that. Thanks